# Why is svg.path's length function returning a divide by zero error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, svg, divide-by-zero

I'm using python to analyze svg image files and I'm trying to tell the length of a path. I have the path

```
M 160.0000 219.2500 L 160.0000 218.6250 Q 160.0000 218.0000 160.0000
217.3750 Q 160.0000 216.7500 159.3750 216.7500 Q 158.7500 216.7500 158.7500
216.1250 Q 158.7500 215.5000 158.7500 217.3750 Q 158.7500 219.2500 159.3750
221.1250 Q 160.0000 223.0000 160.6250 224.8750 Q 161.2500 226.7500 161.8750
228.0000 Q 162.5000 229.2500 163.1250 229.8750 Q 163.7500 230.5000 163.7500
231.1250 Q 163.7500 231.7500 163.1250 230.5000 Q 162.5000 229.2500 160.6250
226.7500 Q 158.7500 224.2500 156.8750 220.5000 Q 155.0000 216.7500 153.7500
214.8750 Q 152.5000 213.0000 151.8750 211.1250 Q 151.2500 209.2500 150.6250
208.6250 Q 150.0000 208.0000 149.3750 206.7500 Q 148.7500 205.5000 149.3750
206.7500 Q 150.0000 208.0000 152.5000 211.1250 Q 155.0000 214.2500 156.8750
217.3750 Q 158.7500 220.5000 160.6250 223.6250 Q 162.5000 226.7500 163.1250
228.6250 Q 163.7500 230.5000 164.3750 231.1250 Q 165.0000 231.7500 165.6250
232.3750 Q 166.2500 233.0000 165.0000 231.1250 Q 163.7500 229.2500 162.5000 
...
```

I use these lines to cast it to a path object but when I try to print the length it gives a divide by zero error.

```
path = svg.path.parse_path(str(PATH_VARIABLE)
print path.length()
```

Comment: Presumably a bug, report it to the author of whatever library you're using to parse the path and determine it's length.